# Purescript's Data.Foldable for_ isn't stack safe?

Tags: purescript

If `actions` is a suitably large array, this creates a stack overflow:

```hs
modifyPerIndex :: forall a. Array (Tuple Int (a -> a)) -> Array a -> Array a
modifyPerIndex actions array = run do
  mutableArray <- thaw array
  for_ actions \(Tuple index action) -> modify index action mutableArray
  pure mutableArray
```

This does not:

```hs
modifyPerIndex :: forall a. Array (Tuple Int (a -> a)) -> Array a -> Array a
modifyPerIndex actions array = run do
  mutableArray <- thaw array
  foreach actions \(Tuple index action) -> void $ modify index action mutableArray
  pure mutableArray
```

I'm assuming that's **why** Control.Monad.ST has its own version of foreach.  `for_`'s `Applicative` & `Foldable` is a much looser constraint than `foreach`'s `Array`. That being said, I'm not sure what `Applicative` & `Foldable` is missing such that `for_` can't be stack safe (or can't be without some other drawback)

I've dug into the source a bit and have noted that `for_` is implemented via `foldr`. I'm not sure where to find Array's foldr instance.

I'm pretty new to a lot of this, just trying to broaden my general understanding. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Foldable` instance for `Array` is [here](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-foldable-traversable/blob/f45f03a5b4a568c79ba36a8764edbb0cbee203e6/src/Data/Foldable.purs#L130-L133), and [here](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-foldable-traversable/blob/f45f03a5b4a568c79ba36a8764edbb0cbee203e6/src/Data/Foldable.js#L3-L14) is the actual code for `foldr`. As you can see, it's stack-safe, because it doesn't use stack at all: it's just a plain old JS loop that mutates an accumulator.

What ends up being *not* stack-safe is `traverse_` (which is `for_` with flipped arguments). Check out [the source](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-foldable-traversable/blob/f45f03a5b4a568c79ba36a8764edbb0cbee203e6/src/Data/Foldable.purs#L250): see that the folding function is `(*>) f`? This means that the result of running `traverse_` on some `Foldable` would be a series of `*>` calls, something like this:

```
traverse_ f [1,2,3,4] == f 1 *> f 2 *> f 3 *> f 4 *> pure unit
```

The key insight here is that the `f` computations are not actually run during `traverse_`'s execution. `traverse_` merely builds a chain of them like that, and only when you go and `bind` it (either with `>>=` or inside a `do`) - that's when that chain gets executed.

And what happens when you try to run a computation built on `*>`? Well, `*>` is an alias for [`applySecond`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/37717776a3693fd5a0a614239f7de1285cba8cdf/src/Control/Apply.purs#L68-L71), which itself utilizes `<*>` - an alias for [`apply`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/37717776a3693fd5a0a614239f7de1285cba8cdf/src/Control/Apply.purs#L48-L51), which is a method of `Apply`, whose [instance for `ST`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-st/blob/1028e084b703d1a7a98a8d923c3603a5610e577e/src/Control/Monad/ST/Internal.purs#L46-L47) uses [`ap`, which in turn relies on monadic bind](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/37717776a3693fd5a0a614239f7de1285cba8cdf/src/Control/Monad.purs#L82-L86).

The body of `ap` binds the first computation, which is `f 1 *> f 2 *> f 3 *> f 4`, but this is not a tail call, so it goes on the stack. In turn, binding that computation leads to trying to bind its own left part, which is `f 1 *> f 2 *> f 3`, and so on, all the way to `f 1`. So the stack blows up.

`traverse_` (and `for_`) can't really do any better, because they're both pure, so they can't run effects, so all they can do is build up a chain of them in hopes that somebody else will execute it later.

And herein lies the answer: why not a special version of `traverse_` that *does* know how to run effects?

**And behold: [`Traversable`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=Traversable)!**

It's a type class somewhat similar to `Foldable`, but with effects built-in. Basically it can fold over a sequence, but the folding function is effectful.

This allows running a series of effects without blowing the stack, but there is a different gotcha: you can't ignore the end result. If you have an array with 100K elements to start, you're going to get another one at the end. Thankfully, this isn't such a big problem as blowing the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links. This makes sense to me in the broad strokes now. I'll dig into this a bit more to make sure I really understand :)