# purescript: Mixing Effect and Array contexts

Tags: arrays, effect, purescript

I'm trying to implement a recursive function to remove empty directories in purescript.  For the following code I get an error about matching Effect with Array.

```
module Test where

import Prelude

import Data.Array as Array
import Effect (Effect)
import Node.Buffer.Class (toArray)
import Node.FS.Stats (isDirectory)
import Node.FS.Sync as FS
import Node.Path (FilePath)
import Prim.Boolean (False)

rmEmptyDirs :: FilePath -> Effect Unit
rmEmptyDirs path = do
  stats <- FS.stat path
  if isDirectory stats then do
    files <- FS.readdir path
    if Array.length files == 0 then
      FS.rmdir path
    else do
      file <- files
      rmEmptyDirs file
  else
    pure unit
```

Here is the error message:

```
Could not match type
Effect
with type
Array
while trying to match type Effect Unit
with type Array t0
while checking that expression rmEmptyDirs file
has type Array t0
in binding group rmEmptyDirs
where t0 is an unknown type
```

I understand that the innermost do block is in an Array context.  I don't know how to "strip off" the Effect from the recursive call to *rmEmptyDirs*.  Putting *Array.singleton $* before the call doesn't help.  *liftEffect* has the opposite effect of what I want to do.  How do I get this compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to thread one context through another is [`traverse`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/5.0.1/docs/Data.Traversable#v:traverse).

Look at the type signature:

```
traverse :: forall a b m. Applicative m => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

First you give it a function `a -> m b` - in your case that would be `rmEmptyDirs` with `a ~ FilePath`, `m ~ Effect`, and `b ~ Unit`.
Then you give it some container `t` (in your case `Array`) full of `a` (in your case `FilePath`).
And it runs the function on every value in the container, and returns the same container full of resulting values `b`, the whole container wrapped in context `m`.

In practice this would look like this:

```
traverse rmEmptyDirs files
```

Then you'd also need to throw away the array of `unit`s, or else the compiler would complain that you're implicitly discarding it. To do that, either bind it to a throwaway variable:

```
_ <- traverse rmEmptyDirs files
```

Or use the `void` combinator, which does the same thing:

```
void $ traverse rmEmptyDirs files
```

---

Another useful thing is [`for`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/5.0.1/docs/Data.Traversable#v:for), which is just `traverse` with arguments flipped, but the flipped arguments allow you to seamlessly pass a lambda-expression as the argument, making the whole thing look almost like a `for` statement from C-like languages. Very handy for cases when you don't want to give a name to the function you're using to traverse:

```
for files \file -> do
  log $ "Recursing into " <> file
  rmEmptyDirs file
```

---

Finally, unrelated hint: instead of `if foo then bar else pure unit`, use the `when` combinator. It would allow you to drop the `else` branch:

```
when (isDirectory stat) do
  file <- FS.readDir ...
  ...
```

And instead of `length ... == 0` use `null`:

```
if Array.null files then ...
```

For `Array` this doesn't matter, but for many other containers `length` is O(n) while `null` is O(1), so it's good to build the habit.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Data.Foldable` has a function called `traverse_` which does exactly what you want.

Comment: `traverse_` isn't stack-safe. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66753139/180286) for more. It's ok when you control the size of the foldable (though I usually prefer `for_` for reasons outlined above), but in this particular case it's dangerous, because you don't control the number of files in a given directory.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. It seems like the fundamental problem here is that `foldr` is not lazy in any way in general, and we would like to hard-code in laziness for doing a `foldr`. This isn't a problem I'm used to coming from Haskell.

Comment: It's not just `foldr`. Nothing is lazy in PureScript. This is a very important point to internalize for anyone coming from Haskell.

Comment: You're correct. But some amount of laziness can be achieved using lambda abstraction - eg we could do `traverse_ _ [] = pure unit; traverse_ f (x:xs) = f x >>= (\_ -> traverse_ f xs)`.

Comment: You're not using `Foldable` here. This is not generalizable for other foldables. So you'd need to write this sort of thing for every foldable separately. Which means a type class. And - surprise! - this is exactly what `Traversable` is.

Comment: Or the other option is making `traverse_` a method of `Foldable` rather than a function. Which would admittedly be rather inelegant.